Hasura DDN supergraph
Anyone can help with this:  .\ddn connector init my_connector -i my_supergraph --dir .
ERR unable to get project dir: hasura.yaml not found in current directory and all its parents.
kind regards
Trying to create a ddn supergraph.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
